# Coreldraw Multiple Contours in VBA

Tags: vba, colors, width, contour, coreldraw

Guys I Am trying to set up a three colour text that is editable

Basically what I want is the text to be black

A 1st contour of 1mm that is white

a 2nd contour of 2mm thick which is black

I have tried the following 2 step contour

```
ActiveSelection.CreateContour cdrContourOutside, 2, 2, , , CreateRGBColor(0, 0, 0), CreateRGBColor(255, 255, 255)
```

this works perfectly as I want and when I edit the text the contour changes to the new text however the contours are both the same width (2mm) and not 1 & 2mm as i want

Also I cant get it to specify the correct color for each contour

If I break apart the 1st contour then add another this gives me contours of different widths and colors but I then loose the edit ability as the contour is not attached to the text

Any Ideas I Know its possible as I have seen a commercial macro that does it

Any Help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can do for you is to show you the object model.  I do not have CorelDraw and therefore cannot test anything.

Here is the link to the [CorelDraw Object Model](http://apps.corel.com/partners_developers/csp/resources/CorelDRAW%20VBA%20Object%20Model.pdf).
http://apps.corel.com/partners_developers/csp/resources/CorelDRAW%20VBA%20Object%20Model.pdf

And here is a link to a [Programming Guide for CorelDraw](http://apps.corel.com/partners_developers/csp/resources/dvba_pg.pdf). 
http://apps.corel.com/partners_developers/csp/resources/dvba_pg.pdf

You can look up "Applying Effects" on page 72 of the programming guide which may help.

I would suggest also looking at creating curves from the `.Shapes` object and then looking at the `TextRange` object. the `TextRange.Text` property is the actual text you want to see and the `TextRange.colorindex` is the color of the text I believe. You will have to do some exploring, but this should help.

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately the links do not work

Comment: try the ones below. I just put in the full text link.  The above should have worked tho.